# Running a method after all custom views has been added

Tags: android

I am trying to animate a custom view in android.

I tried running my method in `onResume()` but I got the same result as running the function in `onCreate()`

Where should I call my function?

Here is my function

```
private void animateAndSetIndexes () {
     for (BarView bv : barViews) {
         Toast.makeText(this, bv.isShown() + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         if (bv.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
                bv.startAnimation(scale_up);
          }
     }
  }



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    animateAndSetIndexes();
}
```

I get "false" Toast which means the view has not been added yet.

Comment: Remove your toast and use logcat instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [addOnPreDrawListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver#addOnPreDrawListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener)) inside the custom view class itself or from the Activity/Fragment. When [onPreDraw](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener#onPreDraw()) is called, start your animation there. Note: You'll want to remove the predraw listener after starting the animation so that `onPreDraw` isn't called repeatedly and restarting the animation.